# Inbox and achievement navigation bar buttons are too close together

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app, global-inbox

The inbox and achievement buttons are now a lot closer together than they were. It may not seem like much but even my skinny fingers struggle to hit the right button... and I know some fat fingered iPhone users...

This is how the buttons were:

[image]

This is how they look now:

[image]

I assume because of the fix to [Achievements navigation bar button in incorrect position](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287742/307988)

---

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Comment: Where did you get 1.6.2.5? I only have 1.6.1.2 for iPad.

Comment: @alexolut Beta. There's a sign up link [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247094/ios-beta-testers-we-miss-you).

Comment: @Cai when did you sign up?

Comment: @ShadowWizard for the beta? 5 or 6 months ago I think

Comment: hmm... so it should still be possible, probably Brian just need to confirm or something. /cc @alex

Comment: @Cai signing up for the Beta channel. Thought that since the app isn't really in beta anymore, maybe it's not possible. :)

Comment: Oh right, yeh Brian still pushes the beta versions... The signup form isn't automatic  though (I had to remind Brian to send me the link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll be fixed in 1.6.3.0, shipping in January.

I didn't think the space was that important, but yeah, those things are really, really close.