# Cannot tap top right reputation change indicator

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The navbar button for the rep/activity log can't be tapped when displaying a rating change (+5).

[image]

Persists between app runs.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 5 (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Intermittent. Happened after launching app from a notification and then not using it for 24 h.

Comment: Rating?  Do you mean reputation?

Comment: I've noticed this as well.  I think the touch area on the nav bar button has decreased.

Comment: Yes, reputation

Comment: I think JAL is right and the touch area is just smaller (I've noticed it too, it's not completely un-touchable though). Probably related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288064/307988) (and the bug that caused that...)

Comment: That's probably it. Seems the regular button is just extremely hard to hit now that I try it on my small screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.3, shipping this month.

Before 1.6.2, we were serving a UIButton as the bar button item's custom view when we showed a reputation change.  This was causing bugs so we used a UIView as the custom view and put both button modes in it.  I'm guessing the internal logic of the navigation bar is such that buttons and button custom views are given a large hit radius, but contents of custom views aren't.

I've overridden `point(inside:with:)` for both the buttons and the custom view so any tap in the navigation bar to the right of the button's left edge is a hit:

**Before**

[image: Screenshot with button hit areas overlaid. The achievement button's hit area is flush with it.]

**After**

[image: Screenshot with button hit areas overlaid. This time, the achievement button has the same vertical hit area as other buttons and a horizontal hit area that extends to the right edge of the screen.]

**Code**

```
private class AchievementButton: UIButton {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        guard let navigationBar: UINavigationBar = nextOfReturnedType() else {
            return super.point(inside: point, with: event)
        }

        // The achievement button is always the last one.  We check that the point is at least the left edge and inside the navigation bar.
        return point.x >= bounds.minX && convert(navigationBar.bounds, from: navigationBar).contains(point)
    }
}

private class AchievementCustomView: UIView {

    // Defer to the button.
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        for view in subviews {
            if view.point(inside: view.convert(point, from: self), with: event) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at and verifying my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289242/242209) as well?